# Function to search dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to write a simple function that when given the parameters of the name of dictionary and the key it will return the correct value. It's basically just going to be used as a quick reference for fitting the correct size gland on correct size cable with correct number of cores.

Here's what I have :

```
cable120 = { 2 : '40mm', 3 : '40mm', 4 : '50mm' }

cable150 = { 2 : '40mm', 3 : '50s', 4 : '50mm' }

cable185 = { 2 : '50s', 3 : '50mm', 4 : '63s' }

cable240 = { 2 : '50mm', 3 : '63s', 4 : '63mm' }

def glandsize(csa,cores):

    try :
        print(csa[cores])

    except : 
        print('Command not recognised. Please try Again.')
        print (' Use As Follows glandsize(cable??, cores)\n For Example If Cable Is 16mm 3 core,\n glandsize(cable16,3')

#glandsize(cable185,2)
```

Now I save this file as GlandSize.py and put it in path environment so I can import it from the Shell to use it.

Here's what happens when I try to use it in the shell :

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import GlandSize
>>> GlandSize.glandsize(cable185, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    GlandSize.glandsize(cable185, 3)
NameError: name 'cable185' is not defined
>>>
```

I don't understand why? I know if i call the function glandsize(cable185,2) in GlandSize.py when I import it, it outputs the correct result.

Why can't I access the correct dictionary in the module from the shell?

I know this is probably a really basic mistake, but I can't seem to get my head around it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you open a new terminal, all of the variables will be empty.
Either refrence to the dictionary inside the file:

```py
>>> import GlandSize
>>> GlandSize.glandsize(GlandSize.cable185, 3)
50mm
```

Or create a new dict:

```py
>>> import GlandSize
>>> cable185 = { 2 : '50s', 3 : '50mm', 4 : '63s' }
>>> GlandSize.glandsize(cable185, 3)
50mm
```